# Is it suitable to use 'ulterior' in meaning of the.. consequence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm, trying to give a name to a link kind, to describe such link as linking to something, 'which base (or cause) includes what was given here (where such link was placed)'. In variants I collected, which may be too few: 'ulterior', 'consecutive', 'further', 'supported' - I feel 'ulterior' brings some intrigue to a content behind the link, labeled with this word. But is 'ulterior' legal, clearly understandable to be used, as example  'link to the ulterior content', in such task?

Thanks

Comment: To bring intrigue to the content, "exclusive" is used nowadays. "ulterior content" doesn't sound right...

Comment: @andrew-tobilko, but 'exclusive' tells nothig about the consequence flow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "ulterior" nearly always used in the phrase "ulterior motive" (meaning a secret reason for doing something)

You sometimes get it with other abstract nouns with a similar meaning "ulterior purpose" or "ulterior intent".  It is not usually used with concrete nouns.

So you might say "The government of the USA had an ulterior link with the Taliban"  This is an abstract sense of "link".  But you wouldn't say "I'll use a URL shortening service to create an ulterior link on my website"

I've found a few uses of "ulterior content".  It seems to be limited in meaning to mean "malware and clickbait"

> Avoid this website.  It seems to be an innocent celebrity news site, but it hosts ulterior content that can take control of your computer and leave you vulnerable to hacking.

Comment: Thanks! The last example made your answer clearer